# Al cargar una vista que contiene iFrame con PDF's, automáticamente aparece ventana de imprimir. PHP

Tags: php, pdf

No tengo ningún código para que se abra la ventana de impresión cuando cargue la página que contiene los PDFs,

en la página donde sucede el problema, hago el include al archivo donde se muestran los PDF's, lo hago así:

```
<div class="tab-pane well" id="messages">
                                <p><?php include("/home/soluci15/public_html/assets/Produccion/Fase_Filtros/documentos.php");?></p>
                            </div>
```

El archivo donde muestran los PDF lo hago con un `for` e imprimo el archivo dentro un `iframe` del siguiente modo:

```
<iframe src="/assets/OperacionesBGA/<?php echo $idf?>/<?php echo $reg["archivo"];?>"   style="border: none;"></iframe>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así muestro los PDF y al cargar esa vista aparece la ventana de impresión de un PDF automáticamente sin dar clic en el icono de imprimir

**¿Cómo evito que la ventana de impresión del archivo PDF salga?**

> **Actualización:** Esto pasa sólo con google chrome, probé com Microsoft Edge y no pasa. Necesito un código para que no pase ya que la mayoría de usuarios usan google chrome.
>
> **Actualizado por solución:** El PDF tenía un Script que hacía que antes de abrir el archivo se imprimiera, eso era lo que provocaba que apareciera la pantalla de impresión.

Comment: Agrega la solución como respuesta y edita el titulo de la pregunta, quitando la parte donde dice solucionado, puedes marcar tu respuesta como [aceptada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: No olvides dar el [tour de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para ver cómo funciona el sitio

Comment: ¿Puede ser el comportamiento por defecto del navegador?

Comment: No, el navegador carga el PDF y pone el Preview dentro del iframe, pero el PDF tiene un Script que hace que al cargar o abrir se imprima.